# Script for opening emacs in two different ways

Tags: bash

I've attempted to write a small script that will by default open emacs with

```
emacs -nw foo
```

by simply typing

```
emacs foo
```

and when I want a window typing

```
emacs foo &
```

The script  I attempted to write looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $2 ]; then
    emacs -nw $1
else
    emacs $1 &
fi
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I try to run the script nothing happens, as if I just hit enter.

Would a more experienced person please advice how to make this script properly?

Comment: Programs in the background cannot interact with the keyboard (receive stdin) and in some cases not even the display (write stdout).

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein GNU emacs has a graphical mode, which is almost definitely what the questioner is using. You cannot know what issuing "emacs" will do without being shown the environment first.

Comment: @ChrisDown I didn't mention emacs in my **comment**. There is no point in providing an **answer** based on assumptions.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein Right, but you're commenting based on the question, of which emacs can be considered an abstraction. By the same virtues, I don't ask about whether the person's version of bash is above version 2.0, or whether they even have emacs in the first place. The question is fundamentally about manipulating the execution of a program in a certain way based upon whether it is running in the foreground or the background in relation to the controlling terminal. There are no assumptions made about if we reduce it to the functional implications, rather than the implementation detail of emacs.

Comment: @ChrisDown That's exactly the reason I chose to write a **comment** and not to give an **answer** to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the script is that if you call it either way (with and without `&`, it sees only one parameter. `bash` has already used the `&` to put the process in the background. If you would try the `fg` after starting with `emacs foo &` you should see emacs with no window, as with the first option.

The second option never gets executed, and it should not have an `&`. What is needed is that the script tests if it runs in the background and decides on that. In a `C` program or in Python I would test if the program group and the terminal foreground process group are the same, but **I**  do not know how to do that in bash shell (Chris Down answer indicates it can be done).

Your invocation strongly implies you want to call this script `emacs` in that case make sure to put the full path to the 'real' emacs in there, to prevent recursion.

If you can live with a Python script to do the job:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

STDOUT_FILENO=1
emacs_cmd = ['/usr/bin/emacs']

if os.getpgrp() == os.tcgetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO):
    emacs_cmd.append('-nw')
emacs_cmd.extend(sys.argv[1:])
subprocess.call(emacs_cmd)
```

It allows you to specify multiple filenames (and additional emacs options) on the commandline.

Comment: No problem with a Python script :), worked great!

Answer (score 2):

As Anthon says, `&` is not an argument to the command, it's part of your shell syntax (it backgrounds the process). Here is a script that can test if the current script is part of the terminal's foreground process group (which will be false if it is backgrounded):

```
#!/bin/bash

# If the STAT column does not end with a plus, this process is not part
# of the terminal's foreground process group (and is backgrounded).

case "$(ps -o stat= -p $$)" in
    *+) exec emacs "$@"  ;;
    *) exec emacs -nw "$@" ;;
esac
```

Comment: That is nifty +1. And I thought me doing such things in python was better than doing this in C, like I did 15+ years ago.